# add header, a command and file content to bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

[Based on this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/663708/828892), I want to automate this process, so i need to add a command and header to a bash script + the contents of a file to run ubuntu 18.04 and create a static arp table. Example my .sh:

```
lan=eth0
awk -F";" '{print $3 " " $2}' infile | xargs -I {} echo {} > outfile
```

note: infile content ip mac

output:

```
 192.168.1.1 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
 192.168.1.2 00:e0:1e:b4:13:43
```

First problem: empty header. Need "#!/bin/sh" or "#!/bin/bash", [solved by](https://askubuntu.com/posts/151681/edit):

```
sed -i -e '1i#!/bin/bash\'
```

Second problem: missing add arp command "arp -i $lan -s". [Solved by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099478/8747573):

```
sed -e 's/^/arp -i $lan -s /'
```

now i need to bind these commands to get this output:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 arp -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.1 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
 arp -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.2 00:e0:1e:b4:13:43
```

What should I fix at my command to add this content? thk

**Update** (solved, but...)

```
lan=eth0
awk -F";" '{print $3 " " $2}' infile | xargs -I {} echo {} | sed -e 's/^/arp -i $lan -s /' | sed -e '1i#!/bin/bash\' > outfile
```

Now the problem is variable $lan

```
 #!/bin/bash
 arp -i $lan -s 192.168.1.1 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
 arp -i $lan -s 192.168.1.2 00:e0:1e:b4:13:43
```

instead of

```
 #!/bin/bash
 arp -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.1 00:e0:1e:b4:12:42
 arp -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.2 00:e0:1e:b4:13:43
```

Comment: ```xargs -I {} echo {}``` is basically same as ```xargs```

Comment: the way it displays the data is different

Comment: Single quotes prevent the expansion of `$lan` inside your sed command - use double quotes if that is what you want